# Copy contents of one file and paste into another text file based on the date

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I have a file named C:\Submitlogs\SubmitLog.txt

```
Log file content:
--------------
User01,15/05/2018,10:26,Submit,CATERGORY1,WEEK46
User01,17/05/2018,10:29,Submit,CATERGORY1,WEEK46
User04,17/05/2018,11:04,Submit,CATERGORY1,WEEK46
User11,17/05/2018,11:09,Submit,CATERGORY1,WEEK46
```

So, If the system date is 17/05/2018 then the batch script should copy only the content (mentioned below) from the above which is of 17/05/2018 and paste it in C:\Submitlogs\Copy.txt

```
User01,17/05/2018,10:29,Submit,CATERGORY1,WEEK46
User04,17/05/2018,11:04,Submit,CATERGORY1,WEEK46
User11,17/05/2018,11:09,Submit,CATERGORY1,WEEK46
```

I have managed to write the below script but I am getting the output as below.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions

set sysdt=%date:~-7,2%/%date:~-10,2%/%date:~-4,4%
echo %sysdt%
set "source=C:\Submitlogs"
set "target=C:\Submitlogs\Copy.txt"
pushd "%source%" 
(for /f "tokens=1,* delims=," %%a in ('findstr /i /C:%sysdt% "SubmitLog.txt"') do ( 
echo(%%b )) > "%target%" 
popd
```

It is taking the values after the searched string. Kindly let me know how to get the full line as the output.

Current output:

```
17/05/2018,10:29,Submit,CATERGORY1,WEEK46
17/05/2018,11:04,Submit,CATERGORY1,WEEK46
17/05/2018,11:09,Submit,CATERGORY1,WEEK46
```

Expected output:

```
User01,17/05/2018,10:29,Submit,CATERGORY1,WEEK46
User04,17/05/2018,11:04,Submit,CATERGORY1,WEEK46
User11,17/05/2018,11:09,Submit,CATERGORY1,WEEK46
```

Comment: `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /i /C:"%sysdt%" "SubmitLog.txt"') do echo(%%a`

Comment: You don't want to parse the lines, so a simple `findstr /i /C:"%sysdt%" "SubmitLog.txt" > "%target%"` should suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use a method of determining the date which will give consistent results regardless of user settings or locales.

This method uses the `RoboCopy` command:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "parent=C:\Submitlogs"
Set "source=SubmitLog.txt"
Set "target=Copy.txt"

If Not Exist "%parent%\%source%" Exit /B
For /F "Tokens=1-3 Delims=/ " %%A In ('RoboCopy/NJH /L "\|" Null'
) Do Set "moment=%%C/%%B/%%A" & GoTo :Break
:Break
Find "%moment%"<"%parent%\%source%">"%parent%\%target%"
```